# GitHub flow, fork for pull requests or just use origin

Tags: git, github, pull-request

What is the recommended/best practice flow for working with pull requests for a **private repo** in GitHub?

Should we as a team each fork the origin repo, and then create PR's from our local fork to the origin? Or should we just all use the origin repo, and push to it, without forking.

What are the benefits of forking?

Comment: That's two questions, correct? (1: howto, 2: should we?)  Do you trust your team enough that they could work on branches? :-)

Comment: The process you are describing has a name. It is called [*GitHub Flow*](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

Comment: I thought it was a question about using https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/ for a private repo and inside a team (probably much too complex).  GitHub Flow is a good place to start.

Comment: But Github Flow does not say if  _Fork & Pull Model_ better than _Shared Repository Model_ or  not

Comment: Exactly, that is my question, does each engineer fork into their own account, or use the organization repo.

Comment: I'm not a git-guru, but iiuc then they have different strengths and you'll have to choose one based on your team's structure and requirements. If you don't know what would fit best, then starting out with "GitHub Flow" wouldn't be a mistake...  (if it works for you then it's less work -- and less control).  The comparison of workflows at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows have pretty pictures :-)